# Convert Third Element in List of List into int more pythonic

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a csv file with names (last_name, name, age) and I want to convert all age attributes into integers. This is a way but I guess there is a more pythonic way to do so? I tried to do it with list comprehension but it didn't quite worked as I wanted.

```
import csv

with open("names.csv") as names_file:
    head , *names = csv.reader(names_file)
    names = [line for line in names]

for i in range(len(names)):
    names[i][2] = int(names[i][2])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most "unpythonic" thing here is the use of indexes in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to handle this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('names.csv')
df["age"] = pd.to_numeric(df["age"])
```

If you want a list just do this:

```py
list_ = df['age'].to_list()
print(list_)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
with open("names.csv") as names_file:
    head, *names = csv.reader(names_file)
    names = [[f, l, int(a)] for f, l, a in names]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
names = [['A', 'B', '20'], ['C', 'D', '30'], ['E', 'F', '40']]  # sample data
for i in names:
    i[2] = int(i[2])
print(names)
```

Which is more succint than:

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    names[i][2] = int(names[i][2])
```

If you have to use list-comprehension then you might do:

```
names = [['A', 'B', '20'], ['C', 'D', '30'], ['E', 'F', '40']]
names = [[int(j) if inx==2 else j for inx, j in enumerate(i)] for i in names]
print(names)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 20], ['C', 'D', 30], ['E', 'F', 40]]
```

Note that this harness nesting and as such is less desirable than above solution concerning readibility.